# Getting Session ID value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-variables, sessionid

I am trying to get the session_id in a Rails 2.2.2 app

I examined the Rails docs and tried a few different things syntactically.

When I do request.inspect or session.inspect, I see @session_id has a value

```
@session_id="BAh7CjoMd...",
```

yet all of the following return nil:

```
request.session[:session_id].inspect 
session[:session_id].inspect
session['session_id'].inspect
```

**Output from session.inspect:**

```
#<CGI::Session:0x104dff278 
@write_lock=true, 
@data={
    :user_id=>nil, 
    :privilege_id=>nil, 
    :after_login=>{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"home"}, 
    :csrf_id=>"34a78413704ac92ee0eb276339b1af76", "flash"=>{}
    }, 
@new_session=false, 
@dbprot=[
        #<CGI::Session::CookieStore:0x104dfe8a0 
        @secret="ee912af8f735b1acf19...", 
        @data={:
                user_id=>nil, 
                :privilege_id=>nil, 
                :after_login=>{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"home"}, 
                :csrf_id=>"34a78413704ac92ee0eb276339b1af76", "flash"=>{}}, 
                @digest="SHA1", 
                @original="BAh7CjoMd...", 
                @cookie_options={
                        "name"=>"_vendor_sandbox_session", 
                                "http_only"=>true, 
                                "secure"=>nil, 
                                "expires"=>nil, 
                                "domain"=>nil, 
                                "path"=>"/"}, 
               @session=#<CGI::Session:0x104dff278 ...>>], 
               @dbman=#<CGI::Session::CookieStore:0x104dfe8a0 
               @secret="ee912af8f735b1acf19...", 
               @data={
                        :user_id=>nil, 
                        :privilege_id=>nil, 
                        :after_login=>{
                    }, 
                    :csrf_id=>"34a78413704ac92ee0eb276339b1af76", 
                    "flash"=>{}}, 
                    @digest="SHA1", 
                    @original="BAh7CjoMd...", 
                    @cookie_options={
                                        "name"=>"_vendor_sandbox_session", 
                                        "http_only"=>true, 
                                        "secure"=>nil, 
                                        "expires"=>nil, 
                                        "domain"=>nil, 
                                        "path"=>"/"
                                    }, 
                    @session=#<CGI::Session:0x104dff278 ...>>, 
                    @session_id="BAh7CjoMd...", 
                    @cgi=#<CGI:0x104f73c30 
                    @cookies={
                                "_vendor_sandbox_session"=>["BAh7CjoMd..."], 

                    }, 
                    @params={}, 
                    @output_hidden=nil, 
                    @multipart=false, 
                    @env_table={
                                    "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", 
                                    "SERVER_NAME"=>"localhost", 
                                    "SERVER_PORT"=>"3000", 
                                    "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"keep-alive", 
                                    "QUERY_STRING"=>nil, 
                                    "PATH_INFO"=>"/login", 
                                    "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2012-02-08)", 
                                    "REQUEST_URI"=>"http://localhost:3000/login", 
                                    "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US,en;q=0.5", 
                                    "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.1", 
                                    "REMOTE_HOST"=>"127.0.0.1", 
                                    "REMOTE_USER"=>nil, 
                                    "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", 
                                    "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0", 
                                    "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"=>"no-cache", 
                                    "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
                                    "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1", 
                                    "HTTP_COOKIE"=>_vendor_sandbox_session=BAh7CjoMdXNlcl9p...", 
                                    "HTTP_PRAGMA"=>"no-cache", 
                                    "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate", 
                                    "HTTP_HOST"=>"localhost:3000"}, 
                                    @output_cookies=nil, 
                                    @stdin=#<StringIO:0x104f73c58
```

Comment: How are you creating the sessions? What's the output of `session.inspect`? If they are in a model, you can use `session.id`. If they are stored in an array or hash, you may have to first identify the individual like `session[0][:session_id]`.

Comment: Updated question such that it now shows session.inspect output

Comment: Justin, I solved this by calling session.session_id. Your help led me to that solution so please submit an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you creating the sessions? What's the output of session.inspect? If they are in a model, you can use session.id. If they are stored in an array or hash, you may have to first identify the individual like session[0][:session_id].

The correct answer turned out to be session.session_id.

Thanks!